# filling color gridient under normal curve in X direction in r

Tags: r, graph, polygon, curve

I am trying to shade under curve (contrast to y direction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012188/r-plot-normal-curves-with-color-gradient)). Just the following is hypothesis of filling direction.

```
curve(dnorm(x,0,1),xlim=c(-3,3),main='Standard Normal')
```

[image]

I am trying to write a function, where I can fill very small polygons with different colors ( I do not know if this is right approach), then it will look like gradient.

The idea is to extend the following filling of single polygon to n polygons.

```
codx <- c(-3,seq(-3,-2,0.01),-2)
cody <- c(0,dnorm(seq(-3,-2,0.01)),0)

 curve(dnorm(x,0,1),xlim=c(-3,3),main='Standard Normal')
 polygon(codx,cody,col='red')
```

I tried to extend it to a function: 
     x1 <- NULL
    y1 <- NULL

```
polys <- function ( lwt, up, itn) {
    x1 <- c(lwt,seq(lwt,up, itn),up)
    y1 <- c(0,dnorm(seq(lwt,up,tn)),0)
    out <- list (x1, y1)
    return (out)
    }
out <- polys(lwt = 0, up = 1, itn = 0.1)

library(RColorBrewer)
plotclr <- brewer.pal(10,"YlOrRd")
```

Neither I could workout the function nor I could brew more colors than 9 this way. Help appreciated.

Comment: In regards to your colour palette, you might want to consider something like: `yrgradient <-colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"))` and use that in the place of `brewer.pal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use segments to achieve "roughly" what you want

```
x <- seq(from=-3, to=3,by=0.01)
curve(dnorm(x,0,1), xlim=c(-3,3))
segments(x, rep(0,length(x)),x,dnorm(x,0,1) , col=heat.colors(length(x)), lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: or use `rect(x[-length(x)], rep(0,length(x)-1), x[-1], dnorm(x,0,1), col=heat.colors(length(x)), lwd=0, border=NA)` to really fill the area between the points ;-) as opposed to drawing lines using segments